# Resolver o erro android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException numa aplicação android que funciona como cliente para receber imagens de um servidor

Tags: android, thread, lado-do-cliente

Estou a tentar fazer uma aplicação Android que vá buscar uma imagem ao computador. O código do lado do servidor (computador) já está implementado e operacional. Utilizando o UDP, peço ao servidor que me envie uma imagem e ele responde com essa mesma imagem. Contudo não estou a conseguir fazer isto. Ainda não percebo muito de Android alguém me poderia ajudar a resolver este problema? O erro está relaccionado com threads, visto que obtenho isto:

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException.

O código que implementei do lado do cliente, ou seja do Android, é o seguinte:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

  private final static int PACKETSIZE = 9000 ;
  public static final int SERVERPORT = 8777;
  public static final int CLIENTPORT = 8667;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button botao1;
    botao1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    botao1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            DatagramSocket socket = null ;

            try
            {
                InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("193.x.x.x");

                // Construção do socket
                socket = new DatagramSocket(CLIENTPORT) ;

                // Construção do pacote datagrama
                String msg = "imagem.jpg";
                byte [] data = msg.getBytes() ;
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, IPAddress, SERVERPORT) ;

                // Envio do pacote
                socket.send(packet) ;
                Log.d("UDP", "A enviar o pedido da imagem...");

                //Preparação da Data para recepção
                packet.setData(new byte[PACKETSIZE]);

                // Espera por uma resposta do Servidor
                socket.receive(packet) ;
                Log.d("UDP", "Imagem recebida...");

                byte[] bytearray = packet.getData();
                Log.d("UDP", " Data armazenada num bytearray");
                final Bitmap new_img = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytearray, 0,bytearray.length);
                ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                image.setImageBitmap(new_img);

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e) ;
            }
            finally
            {
                if(socket != null)
                    socket.close() ;
            }   


        }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No Android o thread principal (também chamado thread de UI, ou *user interface*) é responsável pela atualização da interface gráfica e portanto deve ser mantido responsivo, isto é, não pode ser tomado por operações longas como por exemplo operações de transmissão de dados pela rede. Essas operações devem ser realizadas em um thread secundário. Por isso o thread principal lança essa exceção `NetworkOnMainThreadException` se você tentar executar uma operação relacionada a rede nele.

Pesquise sobre `AsyncTask`. Aqui mesmo no Stack Overflow em português tem vários exemplos.